# How to create circle animation like this in Flutter?

Tags: animation, flutter

I'd like to implement circle animation for profile pictures like Instagram story something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDmR8jZWb04).
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try using the [dashed_circle](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dashed_circle) package to create instagram story like circle (look at the image below). To create a simple spinning version you can add two rotation using the [Transform.rotate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.rotate.html) constructor.

The first rotation has to be the parent widget of the dashed circle. The second rotation should surround the child widget of the dashed circle with the opposite angle of the first rotation.

To create the effect of the dashes slowling merging to a single line, you can slowly decrease the gap property of the `dashed_circle`.

I gave it a go and tried myself at a quick demo, to show you an example implementation:

[image: Bill Gates Story]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dashed_circle/dashed_circle.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RotateAnimationDemo(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RotateAnimationDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => RotateAnimationDemoState();
}

class RotateAnimationDemoState extends State<RotateAnimationDemo>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  Animation base;
  Animation inverted;
  Animation gap;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3));

    base = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeOut);

    inverted = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: -1.0).animate(base);

    gap = Tween<double>(begin: 3.0, end: 0.0).animate(base)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => controller.forward(),
      child: RotationTransition(
        turns: base,
        child: DashedCircle(
          gapSize: gap.value,
          dashes: 20,
          color: Colors.deepOrange,
          child: RotationTransition(
            turns: inverted,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 60.0,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Bill_Gates_Buys_Skype_%285707954468%29.jpg/2560px-Bill_Gates_Buys_Skype_%285707954468%29.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```